# How to pass in-memory images through ExternalEvaluate?

Tags: image-processing, external-calls, python

Version 11.2 has a new import/export format PythonExpression.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work out-of-the-box with images:

[image]

And using the ImageData directly is too slow:

[image]

Anyhow, I have some image processing functionality in Python, my question is *how can I use ExternalEvaluate to call my function on an image from within Mathematica?*

Here's the naive approach (which clearly fails at ToString):

```
script = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "functions.py"}];
Export[script, "
  from scipy import misc

  def process_image(img):
    new_img = img # process the image with python
    return misc.imresize(new_img, (20,20), interp='bilinear')

  ", "Text"];
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[session, File[script]];

img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
ExternalEvaluate[session, "img = " <> ExportString[img, {"Base64", "PNG"}]] (*fixme*)
ExternalEvaluate[session, "process_image(img)"]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `ExportString` as PNG. Presumably scipy can import that data (I believe PIL can import from PNG string).

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm not sure that would be efficient or simple

Comment: I mean you could export to file? But this is one of the major flaws Szabolcs identified with ExternalEvaluate. Can't pass these things in memory.

Comment: This may be worth trying again with v12, [there have been some upgrades to this area](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=49963087#49963087).

Answer (score 2):

Here I successfully received, decode and show the image with the help of `io`, `PIL`, `base64` libraries (`PIL` should be installed):

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];

session = StartExternalSession["Python"];

ExternalEvaluate[session, 
  "import io;from PIL import Image;import base64;"];

ExternalEvaluate[session, 
 "img = " <> 
  ExportString[ExportString[img, {"Base64", "PNG"}], 
   "PythonExpression"] <> ";"] 

ExternalEvaluate[session, "image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(img)));image.show();"]

DeleteObject[session]
```

Because there is `\n` in `ExportString[img, {"Base64", "PNG"}]`, you could also use `'''` (triple quotes):

```
ExternalEvaluate[session, 
 "img = '''" <> ExportString[img, {"Base64", "PNG"}] <> "''';"]
```